# [stompit STOMP client]Failover not working properly with STOMP producer

Tags: javascript, node.js, activemq-classic, stomp

I am using [stompit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stompit) STOMP client. github - https://github.com/gdaws/node-stomp.

I am using [ConnectFailover](http://gdaws.github.io/node-stomp/api/connect-failover/)  API for reconnect management. I have below code:

var stompit = require('stompit')
var reconnectOptions = {
    'maxReconnects': 100,
    'randomize'    : false
};

var connManager = new stompit.ConnectFailover("failover:(stomp://mqbroker.nyc:61613,stomp://failovermqbroker.nyc:61613)", reconnectOptions);

connManager.on('error', function(error) {
    var connectArgs = error.connectArgs;
    var address = connectArgs.host + ':' + connectArgs.port;
    console.error('Could not connect to ' + address + ' : ' + error.message);
});

connManager.on('connecting', function(connector) {
    var address = connector.serverProperties.remoteAddress.transportPath;
    console.log('Connecting to ' + address);
});

var totalMsgs = 50;
var count = 0;
var delayMs = 10000;

connManager.connect(function(error, client, reconnect) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("terminal error, given up reconnecting: " + error);
        return;
    }
    client.on('error', function(error) {
        // destroy the current client
        client.destroy(error);
        // calling reconnect is optional and you may not want to reconnect if the
        // same error will be repeated.
        reconnect();
    });

   var sendParams = {
       'destination' : '/queue/myqueue',
       'persistent'  : 'true'
   }

   function sendMsg (){
       setTimeout( function () {
           console.log ('sending message ' + (count));
           client.send(sendParams).end('Hello number ' + (count));
           if (count++ < totalMsgs) {
             sendMsg(count);
           }
           else {
             client.send(sendParams).end('DISCONNECT');
             client.disconnect();
             console.log("Done.");
           }
         }, delayMs);
    }

   sendMsg();
});

The problem is that When the client gets disconnected from message broker, The producer keeps executing the sendMsg code and this causes loss of 2-3 messages in between. I want the client to stop executing when in disconnected state and resume when it is connected to failover instance.

Am I using the API incorrectly? What will be correct way to achieve this?

Have hacked at it for some time but this API lacks little documentation on how to use the features. Appreciate all the help.

Thanks,
xabhi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with API but the with setTimeout code. I should clear the timeout when the client sees a connection failure.